# CodeBlocks error in graphics library

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi, winbgi

I executed the following code in codeblocks IDE-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\TC\BGI");
    line(100, 200, 150, 250);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and while debugging my code stopped at this point in graphics.h

```
int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
```

I have included the WinBGIm library.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like issue with initialization of graphics driver.

What is the output of following code on your IDE?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    int errorcode = graphresult();
    if (errorcode != grOk)
    {
        cout << "Graphics error: " <<  grapherrormsg(errorcode) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    line(100, 200, 150, 250);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried executing this code and it gives the same error.

Comment: @Akash21795: Can you run the program again. This time replacing `"C:\TC\BGI"` with `"C:\\TC\\BGI"`? Make sure there is a `BGI` directory in path `"C:\TC"`

Comment: I tried replacing the path "C:\\TC\\BGI" and the program is terminating at the same point again.I am sure about the path.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `right` twice on this line in graphics.h:

`int right=0, int right=INT_MAX`

Change the line to this:

`int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX`

Answer (score 0):

You should correct **graphics.h** in this way:

```
int left=0;
int top=0;
int right=INT_MAX;
int bottom=INT_MAX;
```