# Main.exe Stopped Working While Compiling A Graphics Code In CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

[image: Please Click Here To Check The Problem ScreenShot]

The above image contains ---
Error
My Code On Graphics
Inshort All You Need To "Diagnosis"

Please help I am trying to create a tictactoe game there but unfortunately its giving the error in beginning only..

Please NOTE- *>The same code is running well in Turbo c++ .
             *>I have fixed the inclusion of the entire package of "winbgim"        step by step.
             *>My OS-Windows 10

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
  int gd=DETECT;
  int gm;
  initgraph(&gd , &gm ,"C:\\TC\\BGI");

  getch();
  closegraph();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and this is my firstquestion asked here.

Comment: Please set a breakpoint at the first line in main (int gd=DETECT) and step through in order to see where your program actually crashes. Are you familiar to debugging? You really should, because its a valuable tool to find and fix errors in your code.

Comment: Erik, I have tested step by step and this problem is being generated as I compile after the initgraph() is being added in the code.Before the adding it runs perfectly...

Comment: Maybe it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563396/codeblocks-error-in-graphics-library

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:
First- declare your path as char* otherwise you will get an error of "deprecated conversion from string const to char*" 
Use this one:

```
 char driver[]="C:\\TC\\BGI";
```

Second- Delete that libbgi file which you previously downloaded to use graphics.h in codeblocks and download a new one using the link below:

https://github.com/stahta01/windows-games/blob/master/WinBGIm/lib/libbgi.a

Then follow the same steps as you must have done earlier:
1. Go to the settings in codeblocks
2. Choose compiler option and then linker settings
3. Add the new libbgi library using ADD option and write this in the right hand side column:

-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32

Now smile!
Everything is set and start coding!
:) 
Hope it works for you !